# Alternative (equivalent?) procedures for finding the change-of-basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

$\S$ Let $\mathcal{B} = \{(1, -2, 1), (2, -3, 3), (-2, 2, -3)\}$. One can readily show this set is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Simply observe that any $\textbf{x}$ in the span of $\mathcal{B}$ is of the form

\begin{align*}
    \textbf{x} &= \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 -2 \lambda_3 \\
        -2 \lambda_1 -3 \lambda_2 +2 \lambda_3 \\
        \lambda_1 + 3 \lambda_2 - 3 \lambda_3
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

for $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$. So, any arbitrary $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ can be expressed by setting the appropriate $\lambda$ coefficients in the definition of $\textbf{x}$. It is only required that

\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
        \lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 -2 \lambda_3 &=x \\
        -2 \lambda_1 -3 \lambda_2 +2 \lambda_3 &= y\\
        \lambda_1 + 3 \lambda_2 - 3 \lambda_3 &= z
    \end{cases} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -2 &|& x \\
        -2 & -3 & 2 &|& y \\
        1 & 3 & -3 &|& z \\
    \end{pmatrix} &\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -2 &|& x \\
        0 & 1 & -2 &|& y +2x \\
        0 & 0 & 1 &|& z - 3x - y \\
    \end{pmatrix} \\
    &\rightarrow\begin{cases}
        \lambda_1 = 3x - 2z \\
        \lambda_2 = -4x - y +2z \\ \tag{1}
        \lambda_3 = -3x - y + z
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Since $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent (the homogeneous system associated to the system above allows only for a trivial solution), it is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$\S$ Imagine we were asked to find the change-of-basis matrix $C$ that takes us from the canonical base $\mathcal{B}'$ to $\mathcal{B}$. We already showed any $v$ in the span of $\mathcal{B}'$ can be uniquely represented via a linear combination of $\mathcal{B}$. Using the solutions of the first section, we know

\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
        (1, 0, 0) &= 3w_1 -4w_2 -3w_3 \\
        (0, 1, 0) &= 0w_1 - w_2 - w_3 \\ \tag{2}
        (0, 0, 1) &= -2w_1 + 2w_2 + w_3
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

for $w_i \in \mathcal{B}$. Then the change-of-basis matrix that takes us from $\mathcal{B}'$ to $\mathcal{B}$ is

\begin{equation*}
    \textbf{C} := \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 0 & -2 \\
        -4 & -1 & 2 \\
        -3 & -1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

$\S$ So now we come to the question. We are always taught to find the change-of-basis matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$ by deducing the linear combinations of $B_2$ that give each vector $\alpha \in B_1$ (see **Equation 2**). However, the matrix deduced from this method is simply the representation of the the system of equations that comes from showing any canonical vector can be reached via the non-canonical set (thus proving the latter is a basis) (**see Equation 1**).

In short, the change-of-basis matrix can be deduced both from **Equation 1** and **Equation 2**. Then $A)$ why the emphasis in using the method of **Equation 2**, based on the basis? Is it simply because it is simpler? What are the theoretical differences between both methods for finding the change-of-basis matrix? Are they completeley equivalent? If not, why is the first never taught (at least it's not in any of my textbooks)? Would finding the change of basis matrix via the procedure of **Equation 1** be impossible if we were dealing with two non-canonical basis?

I'm very new to linear algebra so excuse the confused tone of my question.

Comment: The two methods are equivalent and Equation 2 exposition is simpler.